# Any algebraic number with modulus $1$ is root of a polynomial with positive coefficients

Tags: polynomials, integers, algebraic-numbers

Given a complex number on the unit circle $e^{i\theta}\neq 1$ that is the root of some polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$, can we always construct a polynomial $p(x)$ with **positive integer coefficients** such that $e^{i\theta}$ is a root of $p(x)$?

Comment: Similar question: if an integral quadratic polynomial $p(x)$ whose roots are $e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta}$ has at least one negative coefficient, is there an integral polynomial $q(x)$ such that $p(x)q(x)$ has all non-negative coefficients?

Comment: @abiessu Such a $p(x)$ must either be $x^2 - x + 1$ or $x^2 -2x + 1$. The former is the 6th cyclotomic polynomial, so it's a factor of $x^5 + \cdots + 1$. The latter is never a factor of a polynomial with non-negative coefficients, hence the possibility is excluded in the question ($e^{i\theta} \neq 1$).

Comment: Are you really requiring $e^{i\theta}$ to be an algebraic integer or just an algebraic number? The question body does not specify a **monic** polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, $e^{i\theta}$ does not have be a root of a monic polynomial. Any polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ is fine. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If $e^{\pm i\theta}$ are zeros of a quadratic in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ it seems to hold. For example $(7x^2-13x+7)(x^2+x+1)^n$ has only positive coefficients when $n\ge10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{2+i 2^{1/4}}{2-i2^{1/4}}$ is on the unit circle and it is a root of the same polynomials in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ as $\frac{2+2^{1/4}}{2-2^{1/4}}>0$ which can't  be the root of a polynomial with non-negative coefficients.

Comment: Spelling it out for the reader unfamiliar with Galois theory. The irreducible (over the rationals) polynomial $f(x)=7x^4-36x^3+42x^2-36x+7$ has two roots on the unit circle and two positive real roots.

Answer (score 7):

Nope, a counter-example are the complex numbers $\mu_{\pm} =-\frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{\varphi}}{\varphi}$.

It is easy to check $|\mu_{\pm}| = 1$ and $\mu_{\pm}$ are the roots of the irreducible polynomial $$q(x) = x^4 -2x^3 -2x^2 -2x + 1$$
This means $\mu_{\pm}$ are algebraic integers.

On the other hand, $q(x)$ have positive real roots $\nu_{\pm} = \varphi \pm \sqrt{\varphi}$. If any $\mu_{\pm}$ is root of $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $q(x) | p(x) \implies p(\nu_{\pm}) = 0$. This implies coefficients of $p(x)$ cannot be all positive.

Comment: A nice idea to use a unit in the denominator to get algebraic integers.