# Roots of polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, natural-numbers, algebraic-numbers

Is there a way to describe/characterize all complex numbers $z$ with $|z| = 1$ such that $z$ is the root of some polynomial with non-negative integer coefficients?

For instance, I've found that such $z$ must (clearly) be algebraic, hence if $z = e^{i\theta}$ then $\theta$ must not be algebraic lest $z$ be transcendental (because $e^a$ is transcendental for any algebraic $a$).

But this is not a sufficient condition as there are algebraic numbers that aren't roots of polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients, as proven in [this SE post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4413618/948575)

Comment: Also, would $\mathbb N[x]$ be a valid way to denote the set of polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients?

Comment: Since $\bar{z}$ must also be a root we can construct the polynomial $z^2 - (e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})z+1  = z^2 - 2 \cos \theta z + 1 = 0$. So one condition could be where $\cos \theta$ is non-positive rational.

Comment: note that one necessary condition is that none of its algebraic conjugates is a positive real